# How can I show data annotation error messages in .NET Core 2.0? Validation messages are not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, data-annotations

I'm coding an application with .NET Core 2.0. I want to control input elements with data annotation.

On the model side, I used data annotation and on the UI side I used the *asp-validation-for* tag helper. The code is below.

In the model class;

```cs
namespace ExampleApp
{
    public class UserViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill this field"),
            Display(Name="Your Name:")]
            public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill this field")]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

In file *UserAdd.cshtml*:

```
@model UserViewModel
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label mb-10">First name</label>
   <input asp-for="@Model.Firstname" class="form-control">
   <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Firstname" class="text-danger">
   </span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label mb-10">Soyadı</label>
   <input asp-for="@Model.Lastname" class="form-control">
   <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Lastname" class="text-danger">
   </span>
</div>
```

Configure method in Startup.cs file;

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

On my Controller Side;

The model's `Isvalid` value equals false when I click the submit button with an empty value of input. But there isn't any error message on the UI page.

Why is an error message not showing in the UI and where is my fault?

Comment: so you have an invalid model `server-side` but you want to then show the errors `client-side`?

Comment: `asp-validation-for="Firstname"`

Comment: @JohnB Yes, Absolutely!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are placing *validate* and *validate.unobtrusive* jQuery in the wrong place or it may be you are missing a *form* tag. So please put this jQuery code in the *head* section of your HTML page and be sure no any other jQuery will be before it and use my design code.

**jQuery validation plugin**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

#### *.cshtml* code

```
<form asp-action="YourActionName">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Firstname" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Firstname" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Firstname" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
 <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` in your `Shared` folder. This file contains validation scripts in the form of a partial view. By default, this file contains the below code:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha256-F6h55Qw6sweK+t7SiOJX+2bpSAa3b/fnlrVCJvmEj1A=">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator && window.jQuery.validator.unobtrusive"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha256-9GycpJnliUjJDVDqP0UEu/bsm9U+3dnQUH8+3W10vkY=">
    </script>
</environment>
```

Now if this validation script has to be used in any View then it can be done using the *RenderPartailAsync* method as shown below (in your case, add the code at the bottom of your `UserAdd.cshtml` file):

```
@section Scripts {
  @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```